# search pipe after 2 letters in angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-pipe

I have seacrh pipe it's working fine, problem is it's search after i type full word, I want to seacrh after two lettrs of input 
this is the code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"   [value]="searchRole"/>
<li *ngFor="let user of roleUserData | SearchRolePipe: 'name':searchRole ;let  i= index" >{{user.name}}</li>

export class SearchRolePipe implements PipeTransform {


  transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {

    if (value === '') {
      return items
    }
     if (!items) {

       return [];
     } else {

      return items.filter(it => it[field] == value);
}
}
```

it's working , my requiremnet is it should search after 2 letters of user input

example if array is like

```
[
{'name': 'abc'}, 
{'name': 'abcde'},
{'name': 'bce'}
```

]
Here **searchRole** is empty public variable
if i am going to search abc then only it giving back result `[{name: abc}]`

But I want if I type 'ab' then it should return

```
[
 {'name': 'abc'}, 
    {'name': 'abcde'}]
```

please any one let me know how to solve it or any other good approach

Comment: And how do you update the property "searchRole"? You are only showing a one-way binding in your code

Comment: I updated my question , can you please check

Comment: So do you want to search for all items that contains your search query? Or the one that starts with the query?

Comment: yes, exact i want like this

Answer (score 4):

this will do what you want

```
// imports in top level  
    import { of, pipe } from 'rxjs';
    import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
// imports in top level 

const namesArray = of('omar', 'ali', 'tota', 'lelo', 'pedo')
.pipe(filter((n: any) => n.indexOf('o') >= 0)); // get names containing letter "o"
namesArray.subscribe(x => console.log('filter,map ', x));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {

    if (value === '') {
      return items
    }
     if (!items) {

       return [];
     } else if( value.length >= 2 ) { //new code here
      return items.filter(it => it[field] == value);
     }else{
      return items; // returning all the items. Filtering starts at 2 letters
     }
```

Comment: what do you want if i only type a single letter?

Comment: then also it should return matched items

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {

    if (!items) {
        return [];
    }

    if (!value || value.length === 0) {
      return items;
    } 

    return items.filter(it => it[field].indexOf(value) >= 0);
}
```